# Sunspot Rails:No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm running sunspot on a rails app and can (I assume) get the search server to run with "rake sunspot:solr:run". Unfortunately I get the ECONNREFUSED error in my search controller when I try to reach the search index.

I have tried turning my firewall completely off with no luck. Changed all the ports in sunspot.yml to 8983 with no luck either. I found out about the command "netstat -anb" but don't know what process to look for. What could be causing this error?

**Edit**

And the following below did not help either since rake sunspot:solr:start does not work.

```
Common Initial Troubleshooting.
If you see: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)) Then perhaps:

You have not started the solr server:
$ rake sunspot:solr:start

An error occurred in starting the solr server (such as not having the Java Runtime        Environment installed). do
$ rake sunspot:solr:run
to run the server in the foreground and check for errors.

If you come across this error in testing but not development, then perhaps you have not     invoked the task with the correct environment:
$ RAILS_ENV=test rake sunspot:solr:run
```

**Edit 2**
sunspot:solr:run also shows the following in the terminal but seems to continue loading other details in the terminal:

```
WARN:  failed SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8983
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

:WARN:  EXCEPTION
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

**More details**

```
INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8983
```

How can I change the port because java.exe is **also** listening on this port. I changed both the sunspot.yml and scripts.conf but solr:run still connects to port 8983.

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Heroku?

Comment: currently it's running locally on webrick

Comment: I once had the same problem. The only thing that solved it for me was to uninstall the gem _and_ remove the solr directory from root. Then I installed the gem again and everything worked. You can leave your code in the models as is. Of course, reindex your models using `sunspot:solr:reindex`

Comment: To change the Solr port, see http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-change-a-port-td490375.html or http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have another instance of Solr running. Try killing all your instances and running it again.